PyFlink: Custom Key Serialization in KafkaSink doesn't work
I'm working with Apache Flink's Python API (PyFlink) and trying to implement custom serialization for the keys in a Kafka producer. My goal is to modify the keys before sending them to a Kafka topic using a custom serialization schema. However, I'm encountering a NullPointerException when trying to use my custom serialization schema in the KafkaSink setup. I am unsure if my approach to implementing the custom serialization is correct or if there is a limitation with PyFlink's support for custom serializers. Here's the code snippet I'm working with:
from pyflink.common.serialization import SerializationSchema

class CustomKeySerializationSchema(SerializationSchema):
    def serialize(self, value):
        # Example modification to the key before serialization
        try:
            modified_value = value + "_custom"
            return modified_value.encode('utf-8')
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error during serialization:", e)
            return None

kafka_producer = KafkaSink.builder() \
    .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
    .set_record_serializer(
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.builder()
            .set_topic_selector(lambda element: "DIJ.test")
            .set_key_serialization_schema(CustomKeySerializationSchema())
            .set_value_serialization_schema(CustomKeySerializationSchema())
            .build()
    ) \
    .build()

Questions:

Is there a known limitation or issue in PyFlink that prevents the use of custom serialization schemas for keys in KafkaSink?
How can I properly implement custom serialization for keys in PyFlink without encountering a NullPointerException?
Are there alternative approaches to achieve custom key serialization in a Kafka producer using PyFlink?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I am unable to find much documentation on custom serializers in the PyFlink context.

I tried reading the source code and documentation. Both were unhelpful.
